# How to link two Realm objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm new to iOS development and currently using Realm as database. My first tableview display Restaurant object and second table display customer objects. How can i link this two objects?. Means when i click each restaurant it will display different customer.

```
class Restaurant: Object {
    dynamic var restname: String = ""
    dynamic var date: String = ""
}

class Customer: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var price: Float = 0.0
    dynamic var drinks: Float = 0.0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You make references to your models like so

```
class Customer: Object {
    dynamic var restaurant: Restaurant?
}
```

You also have the possibility to get reverse relationship with `LinkingObjects(fromType:, property:)`

You can write in your other model

```
class Restaurant: Object {
    let customers = LinkingObjects(fromType: Customer.self, property: "restaurant") 
}
```

That way you don't duplicate relationships.

Comment: I tried adding your code to define an inverse relationship between the objects. However I'm getting the error `Cannot invoke initializer for Type 'LinkingObjects<Object>' with an argument list of type '(fromType: Users.Type, property: String)'` Please rectify your answer.

Comment: @Jobs I made an edit to match the current API recommendations. This works for sure :) I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, in Restaurant class put this:

```
dynamic var _customer = Optional(Customer())
```

or in Customer class put this line:

```
dynamic var _restaurant = Optional(Restaurant())
```

NOTE: Name of variable with lower dash, may be any name, my habit is to put lower dash